# Reformat links in string with PHP

Tags: php, string, html-parsing

I have text with a number of links. I want to reformat the text such that each url occurs *after* the name of its corresponding link and is wrapped in parenthesis - and all tags are removed (I'm writing this to CSV)

So for example,

```
<a href="http://test.com">TestWebsite1</a>
```

Becomes...

```
TestWebsite1 (http://test.com)
```

The approach I'm thinking is a bit tedious:

```
get index of each occurrence of "<a"
use regex to get all text following that up to next occurrence of ">"
find next occurrence of <
insert text at that index 
str_replace "<a href=“ with "(" 
etc
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way...

Comment: yes, there is, and it's called DOM.. regex + html leads to human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together, mass hysteria...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php - look at the examples.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps should look at markdown converter. and just use that format.

https://github.com/erusev/parsedown

Answer (score 0):

Please use a proper HTML parser:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a href="http://test.com">TestWebsite1</a>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[@href]') as $anchor) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $anchor->textContent, $anchor->getAttribute('href'));
}
```